# How can I solve this integral by making any substitution?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

The integral is 
$$\int{\left[\frac{\sin^8(x) - \cos^8(x)}{1 - 2 \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}\right]}dx$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485420/how-to-solve-this-indefinite-integral-by-any-substitution

Comment: Why did you repost? There were no answers to the previous version, so you should have just edited.

Comment: @Gribouillis Lab Bhattacharjee's link is ok. It just points at the earlier identical question Pegasus deleted themself. You need 10k rep points to see deleted posts.

Comment: Also, Pegasus, please spend a while familiarizing yourself with the site culture.  Check out [the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [the  guidelines specific to Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). This site is a wonderful resource, but we hold the askers to some standards. You will quickly figure out what you can expect, and also what is expected from you.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks for the reminder. It's only my second question on this site so I didn't know the rules.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\sin^8(x)- \cos^8(x)=(\sin^2(x)- \cos^2(x))(1-2\sin^2(x) \cos^2(x))$

Comment: It would be even better if you add a proof of this identity.

Comment: Well I’m pretty new to this site I’m not sure how much to give especially for a problem where the OP showed no effort towards a solution. I figured he/she could work it out. If it is homework they will need to justify that themselves anyway

Comment: I don't think the identity holds correct. @corey

Comment: @Pegasus The identity is correct, I just verified it.

Answer (score 1):

this integer can be reduced using the double angle sine and cosine formula.

let
$$ I=\int \frac{sin^8(x)-cos^8(x)}{1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}dx $$
$$ I=\int \frac{(sin^4(x)+cos^4(x))(sin^4(x)-cos^4(x))}{1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}dx $$
$$ I=\int \frac{(sin^4(x)+2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)+cos^4(x)-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x))(sin^4(x)-cos^4(x))}{1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}dx $$
$$ I=\int \frac{((sin^2(x)+cos^2(x))^2-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x))(sin^2(x)+cos^2(x))(sin^2(x)-cos^2(x))}{1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}dx $$
$$ I=\int \frac{(1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x))(sin^2(x)-cos^2(x))}{1-2sin^2(x)cos^2(x)}dx $$ 
$$ I=\int sin^2(x)-cos^2(x) dx=\frac{-1}{2}\int 2cos(2x) dx =\frac{-1}{2}sin(2x)+C $$

Comment: I edited the answer make sure you check